# sympy AttributeError: 'Pow' object has no attribute 'sin'

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640759/what-causes-this-error-attributeerror-mul-object-has-no-attribute-cos-in) which says namespace conflict is one reason for this error. I am falling to this error frequently. So, I'd like to learn **what exactly is happening here?** What is expected by the library?

EDIT: `fun = lambda x:  4*x*(np.sin(x**2) - 3)*np.cos(x**2)` comes from a test case, so practically I am bound to use it as function 'fun'. Sorry for missing that information. Kindly discuss respecting this constraint.

EDIT2: This is an error reproducing code, not the full script. **Task** is to calculate differentiation of an input function that can evaluate numpy arrays by using a forward difference approximation with a perturbation ∆=10 −8.

Code:

```
import sympy
import numpy as np 

# TESTING...
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
fun = lambda x:  4*x*(np.sin(x**2) - 3)*np.cos(x**2)  
print fun
h = 10e-8  #perturbation
print fun(x)
print fun(x+h)
df = (fun(x+h) - fun(x)) / h
print "diff is:", df
```

Error:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x000000001068E2E8>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-75-0582d8ebb11b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/test_hw3.py', wdir='D:')

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "D:/test_hw3.py", line 23, in <module>
    print fun(x)

  File "D:/test_hw3.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    fun = lambda x:  4*x*(np.sin(x**2) - 3)*np.cos(x**2)
AttributeError: 'Pow' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to use [`sympy.sin`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric.sin)/`cos` instead of `np.sin`/`cos`. Numpy does not know how to work with sympy expressions.

```
fun = lambda x: 4 * x * (sympy.sin(x**2) - 3) * sumpy.cos(x**2)
```

On the other hand, if you must keep `np.sin`, then you should *not* send a sympy variable to `fun`. Instead, `df` should become a function itself.

```
fun = lambda x:  4*x*(np.sin(x**2) - 3)*np.cos(x**2)  
h = 1e-8

df = lambda x: (fun(x+h) - fun(x)) / h

# usage:
df( np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]) )
```

---

BTW, sympy already has a [`diff`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.function.diff) function to compute the derivative.

```
df = sympy.diff(fun(x), x)
```

Comment: Can you please review your answer against my edits. Thanks.

Comment: @devautor Are you really supposed to use sympy?

Comment: Yes, I am. Do you have alternatives? [Though my requirements won't let me pursue them for this task]

Comment: @devautor What is expected from `df`?

Comment: Task is to calculate differentiation of an input function that can evaluate numpy arrays by using a forward difference approximation with a perturbation ∆=10 −8.

Comment: @devautor That doesn't sound like sympy needs to be involved

Comment: Then, how should I get an expression/function for differentiation? It should be available to be evaluated on any given 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

Function `fun` uses `np.sin` and `np.cos`, which are numpy functions that accept as arguments only [data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) recognized by numpy. When you do `fun(x)` you are giving as argument to numpy functions a sympy object, which numpy does not recognize, raising this "cryptic" error message.

Note that when you define `fun` using the statement `lambda x:...`, `x` is treated in the definition as a dummy variable name for a valid data type (even though you have defined `x` above as a sympy symbol).