# Error using 'exp' in sympy -TypeError and Attribute Error is displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

I want solve differential equation using sympy on Python3. My equation is relatively simple with two variables. However, the equation has log, power, and exp operators. Whether I use np.exp or sym.exp, it gives me one of the two errors below:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'log'
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

I am importing numpy and sympy separately. I am not sure if these two libraries are conflicting.

```
import math
import sympy as sym
from sympy import symbols, diff, exp, log, power
from sympy import *

data = [3, 33, 146, 227, 342, 351, 353, 444, 556, 571, 709, 759, 836, 860, 968, 1056, 1726, 1846, 1872, 1986, 2311, 2366, 2608, 2676, 3098, 3278, 3288, 4434, 5034, 5049, 5085, 5089, 5089, 5097, 5324, 5389,5565, 5623, 6080, 6380, 6477, 6740, 7192, 7447, 7644, 7837, 7843, 7922, 8738, 10089, 10237, 10258, 10491, 10625, 10982, 11175, 11411, 11442, 11811, 12559, 12559, 12791, 13121, 13486, 14708, 15251, 15261, 15277, 15806, 16185, 16229, 16358, 17168, 17458, 17758, 18287, 18568, 18728, 19556, 20567, 21012, 21308, 23063, 24127, 25910, 26770, 27753, 28460, 28493, 29361, 30085, 32408, 35338, 36799, 37642, 37654, 37915, 39715, 40580, 42015, 42045, 42188, 42296, 42296, 45406, 46653, 47596, 48296, 49171, 49416, 50145, 52042, 52489, 52875, 53321, 53443, 54433, 55381, 56463, 56485, 56560, 57042, 62551, 62651, 62661, 63732, 64103, 64893, 71043, 74364, 75409, 76057, 81542, 82702, 84566, 88682]
n = len(data)
tn = data[n-1]


b, c = sym.symbols('b c', real=True)

f = -(-n +sum(np.log(b*c*np.power(data,(c-1))*exp(-b*np.power(data,c)))))

diff(f,b)
diff(f,c)
```

Expecting to derive partial derivative of equation 'f' with respect to parameters 'b' and 'c'

This is not similar to [What causes this error (AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos') in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640759/what-causes-this-error-attributeerror-mul-object-has-no-attribute-cos-in) since the cause is not the namespace issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes this error (AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos') in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640759/what-causes-this-error-attributeerror-mul-object-has-no-attribute-cos-in)

Comment: Problem is you trying to apply numpy log and exp to a list of sympy objects. Those functions are meant to work with arrays of numbers.  Don't mix numpy and sympy without a clear understanding of how they work.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh No, I read through that post before posting this. That was a namespace issue because of 
    from sympy import *
    from numpy import *

Comment: @hpaulj I tried using sym.log and sym.power but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: `np.log` is the culprit here, try playing around with it and see if you can get it to work

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I agree. Changing np.log to sym.log helps, however, since I have the np.power term inside the log term, this returns the same error. I tried breaking it down and switched between sym.log, sym.power and np.log

Comment: Why are you using numpy at all?  Or pandas and scipy?

Comment: @hpaulj I need these libraries for latter use in my code. pandas or scipy is not needed here. I will edit the code to avoid confusion.

Comment: @hpaulj the power term has an array and it looks like sympy is unable to handle it.

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh  the power term has an array and it looks like sympy is unable to handle it.

Comment: there you go, you solve it, now self answer and accept it

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I am trying to find a way to solve this. I will post the solution as soon as I resolve this. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: `sympy.log` and `np.log` raise different issues.  Don't confuse them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `isympy` session (similar to your imports), plus a `np` import:

```
In [12]: data = [1,2,3,4,5]                                                  

In [13]: np.power(data,c)                                                    
Out[13]: array([1, 2**c, 3**c, 4**c, 5**c], dtype=object)

In [14]: b*c*np.power(data,c)                                                
Out[14]: array([b*c, 2**c*b*c, 3**c*b*c, 4**c*b*c, 5**c*b*c], dtype=object)
```

So far these work.  When `numpy` functions and operators encounter an object dtype array (non-numeric ones), they try to apply corresponding operators or methods of the objects.  `b` and `c` as `symbols` do respond to `**` and `*`.

But `np.log` applied to the object array fails with your error message.  The elements of the array a sympy `Mul` objects:

```
In [17]: type(Out[14][0])                                                    
Out[17]: sympy.core.mul.Mul
In [18]: Out[14][0].log()                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'log'
```

Same for `np.exp`.

`math.log` expects a number, so it won't work with array or the sympy objects either.

`sympy.log(Out[14][0])` works - the argument is a sympy `Mul`.  But it doesn't work with `Out[14]` which a numpy array.

===

I know `numpy` a lot better than `sympy`.  But I was able to get this sequence of calculations to work:

```
In [24]: [d**c for d in data]     # list comprehension                                                
Out[24]: 
⎡    c   c   c   c⎤
⎣1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ⎦

In [25]: [b*c*num**c for num in data]                                        
Out[25]: 
⎡      c       c       c       c    ⎤
⎣b⋅c, 2 ⋅b⋅c, 3 ⋅b⋅c, 4 ⋅b⋅c, 5 ⋅b⋅c⎦

In [26]: [log(b*c*num**c) for num in data]                                   
Out[26]: 
⎡             ⎛ c    ⎞     ⎛ c    ⎞     ⎛ c    ⎞     ⎛ c    ⎞⎤
⎣log(b⋅c), log⎝2 ⋅b⋅c⎠, log⎝3 ⋅b⋅c⎠, log⎝4 ⋅b⋅c⎠, log⎝5 ⋅b⋅c⎠⎦

In [27]: sum([log(b*c*num**c) for num in data])                              
Out[27]: 
              ⎛ c    ⎞      ⎛ c    ⎞      ⎛ c    ⎞      ⎛ c    ⎞
log(b⋅c) + log⎝2 ⋅b⋅c⎠ + log⎝3 ⋅b⋅c⎠ + log⎝4 ⋅b⋅c⎠ + log⎝5 ⋅b⋅c⎠
```

`sympy.sum` expects an iterable, which this list qualifies.

Now I can do the `sympy.diff`

```
In [29]: diff(sum([log(b*c*num**c) for num in data]),b)                      
Out[29]: 
5
─
b

In [30]: diff(sum([log(b*c*num**c) for num in data]),c)                      
Out[30]: 
     -c ⎛ c               c  ⎞    -c ⎛ c               c  ⎞    -c ⎛ c      
1   5  ⋅⎝5 ⋅b⋅c⋅log(5) + 5 ⋅b⎠   4  ⋅⎝4 ⋅b⋅c⋅log(4) + 4 ⋅b⎠   3  ⋅⎝3 ⋅b⋅c⋅l
─ + ────────────────────────── + ────────────────────────── + ─────────────
c              b⋅c                          b⋅c                          b⋅

         c  ⎞    -c ⎛ c               c  ⎞
og(3) + 3 ⋅b⎠   2  ⋅⎝2 ⋅b⋅c⋅log(2) + 2 ⋅b⎠
───────────── + ──────────────────────────
c                          b⋅c
```

`[log(item) for item in Out[14]]` produces the same output as `Out[26]`.  `Out[14]` is simply the object array equivalent of the `Out[25]` list.

Comment: sympy.log works but it returns the error that you reported above when you combine it with a power of an array. Is there an alternative method to compute power of an array that is compatible with sympy?

Comment: `sympy.log` is designed to work with `sympy` objects, but does not work with `numpy` arrays.  Why should it?

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this problem. Using list comprehension solves the problem. Here is my revised code that works:    f = -(-n +sum([sym.log(b*c*(num**(c-1))*sym.exp(-b*(num**c))) for num in data]))

Answer (score 0):

As per @hpaulj suggestion, I was able to solve this by using list comprehension. The working code is below:

```
f = -(-n +sum([sym.log(b*c*(num**(c-1))*sym.exp(-b*(num**c))) for num in data]))
```