# Multivariate Newton's method for equations derived using Sympy

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, newtons-method, scipy-optimize

Converting Sympy derived equations to be compatible with scipy.optimize.newton for multivariate problem

I referred to [Error using 'exp' in sympy -TypeError and Attribute Error is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210112/error-using-exp-in-sympy-typeerror-and-attribute-error-is-displayed). I found out that using lambdify will make the symbolic equations compatible with other packages such as numpy and scipy.

This is a continuation of my previous post: [Error using 'exp' in sympy -TypeError and Attribute Error is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210112/error-using-exp-in-sympy-typeerror-and-attribute-error-is-displayed?noredirect=1#comment99042685_56210112)

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
import scipy.optimize
from sympy import symbols, diff, exp, log, power
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

data = [3, 33, 146, 227, 342, 351, 353, 444, 556, 571, 709, 759, 836, 860, 968, 1056, 1726, 1846, 1872, 1986, 2311, 2366, 2608, 2676, 3098, 3278, 3288, 4434, 5034, 5049, 5085, 5089, 5089, 5097, 5324, 5389,5565, 5623, 6080, 6380, 6477, 6740, 7192, 7447, 7644, 7837, 7843, 7922, 8738, 10089, 10237, 10258, 10491, 10625, 10982, 11175, 11411, 11442, 11811, 12559, 12559, 12791, 13121, 13486, 14708, 15251, 15261, 15277, 15806, 16185, 16229, 16358, 17168, 17458, 17758, 18287, 18568, 18728, 19556, 20567, 21012, 21308, 23063, 24127, 25910, 26770, 27753, 28460, 28493, 29361, 30085, 32408, 35338, 36799, 37642, 37654, 37915, 39715, 40580, 42015, 42045, 42188, 42296, 42296, 45406, 46653, 47596, 48296, 49171, 49416, 50145, 52042, 52489, 52875, 53321, 53443, 54433, 55381, 56463, 56485, 56560, 57042, 62551, 62651, 62661, 63732, 64103, 64893, 71043, 74364, 75409, 76057, 81542, 82702, 84566, 88682]
n = len(data)
tn = data[n-1]


b, c = sym.symbols('b c', real=True)

f = -(-n +sum([sym.log(b*c*(num**(c-1))*sym.exp(-b*(num**c))) for num in data]))

bh = lambdify((b,c),diff(f,b),"numpy")
ch = lambdify((b,c),diff(f,c),"numpy")

sol = scipy.optimize.newton([bh,ch],(0.00404,1.0))
print(sol)
```

I can't seem to get the Newton's method working. Any information or resources is appreciated.

Comment: `newton` works for scalar functions. For multidimensional functions see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#id2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining symbols, we can use the 'DeferredVector' in sympy to define the symbols. Instead of

```
b, c = sym.symbols('b c', real=True)
f = -(-n +sum([sym.log(b*c*(num**(c-1))*sym.exp(-b*(num**c))) for num in data]))
bh = lambdify((b,c),diff(f,b),"numpy")
ch = lambdify((b,c),diff(f,c),"numpy"
```

do the following:
    x = DeferredVector('x')
    f = -(-n +sum([sym.log(x[0]*x[1]*(num**(c-1)) for num in data]))

Now use diff w.r.t x[0] and x[1] and run the scipy.optimize.newton().

Answer (score 1):

According to the [scipy.optimize.newton](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) your `x0` should be a scalar and not an array or tuple (which is what you are passing to `scipy.optimize.newton()` in your code). Fortunately, [scipy.optimize.fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve) can also find the zero position and accepts arrays as `x0`.

From what I see, you are making life harder by using `sympy`, when you can simply use `numpy`, which speeds your code (you can avoid the `for` loop). The following example shows you how it can be used (hope it helps):

```py
import warnings 
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
# filter warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

data = np.array([3, 33, 146, 227, 342, 351, 353, 444, 556, 571, 709, 759, 836, 860, 968,
        1056, 1726, 1846, 1872, 1986, 2311, 2366, 2608, 2676, 3098, 3278, 3288,
        4434, 5034, 5049, 5085, 5089, 5089, 5097, 5324, 5389,5565, 5623, 6080, 
        6380, 6477, 6740, 7192, 7447, 7644, 7837, 7843, 7922, 8738, 10089,
        10237, 10258, 10491, 10625, 10982, 11175, 11411, 11442, 11811, 12559, 
        12559, 12791, 13121, 13486, 14708, 15251, 15261, 15277, 15806, 16185,
        16229, 16358, 17168, 17458, 17758, 18287, 18568, 18728, 19556, 20567,
        21012, 21308, 23063, 24127, 25910, 26770, 27753, 28460, 28493, 29361,
        30085, 32408, 35338, 36799, 37642, 37654, 37915, 39715, 40580, 42015,
        42045, 42188, 42296, 42296, 45406, 46653, 47596, 48296, 49171, 49416,
        50145, 2042,  52489, 52875, 53321, 53443, 54433, 55381, 56463, 56485,
        56560, 57042, 62551, 62651, 62661, 63732, 64103, 64893, 71043, 74364,
        75409, 76057, 81542, 82702, 84566, 88682])

n    = len(data)
tn   = data[n-1]

f        = lambda b, c: n - np.sum(np.log(b * c * data**(c-1) * np.exp(-b * data**c)))
obj_func = lambda x   : np.array([f(x[0], x[1]) - x[0], f(x[0], x[1]) - x[1]])


x0  = np.array([0.00404, 1.0])
sol = opt.fsolve(obj_func, x0 = x0)
print('b, c = ', sol)
```

Output:

```
b, c =  [0.01737803 0.4300348 ]
```

Comment: Thank you. For the objective function, I have specified in my code, it is easier to use fsolve or root. But, I need to use Newton's method for much complicated objective function so I am trying to get this simple function working before moving on to a complex one,

Comment: Well the problem is that `scipy.optimize.newton` does not support multidimensional functions so you will need to consider finding a different approach. That or solve for each variable at a time using a loop but that would be an ugly slow solution imo. Good luck.