# Issue with implementing sympy into newtons method

Tags: python, sympy, newtons-method

I was trying to make a calculator for newtons method given a function, I've got everything down except that I keep running into an issue when I'm trying to do log of a different base or `ln(x)`.

I'd appreciate the help!

```py
import sympy as sp


x = sp.symbols('x')

# ask for expression and initial guess
expression = input('input function: ')
initial = float(input('input an initial guess: '))
iterate = int(input('input how many times you want it to iterate: '))


# find derivative of function
f_prime = sp.diff(expression, x)

f = sp.lambdify(x, expression, 'numpy')
df = sp.lambdify(x, f_prime, 'numpy')


# newtons method rounded to 8 decimal places
for i in (1, iterate):
    i = initial - (f(initial)/df(initial))
    initial = round(i, 8)

print(f'The root is {initial} after {iterate} iterations')
```

Everytime I put in log of a different base it would give me

```py
TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType or a name error
```

for `ln(x)` it would give me

```py
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'ln'. Did you mean: 'n'?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multivariate Newton's method for equations derived using Sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228036/multivariate-newtons-method-for-equations-derived-using-sympy)

Comment: There is no `ln` function in Python. Try `sp.ln`.

Comment: when I did that it  gave me this error 
ValueError: Error from parse_expr with transformed code: "Symbol ('sp' ).ln (Symbol ('x' ))"

Comment: What expression are you using?  Using expressions with `ln` (or other transendentals) in `lambdify` is tricky.  Also, show the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your `expression = input('input function: ')` is of type string. Before creating `f = sp.lambdify(...)` you need to convert that `expression` into a symbolic expression. `sympify` is the command you need to use:

```
expression = sp.sympify(input('input function: '))
```

Comment: I added a print statement after f_prime = sp.diff(expression, x) to compare the derivatives of log(x) and ln(x) but just ended up getting the same result for both of them. Every other math function works fine except these two

Comment: In Sympy, `log` is `ln`. If you want a logarithm with a different base, you have to write `log(x, your_base)`.