# How can I obtain the real or the imaginary part of a complex exponential function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter, sympy, complex-numbers

I am using Jupyter in particular. e.g from the equation e<sup>2+j</sup>, how can I seperate it in it's real part (e<sup>2</sup>) and into it's imaginary (e<sup>j</sup>)?
I have tried:
`exp(complex(2,1)).real`
However the error that follows it is: **'Mul' object has no attribute 'real'**.
An other solution might be to implement the eulers formula to seperate it as cos(2)+j­·sin(1) but no success so far. Generally the problem is when complex numbers appear in power position rather than in usual format (2+j). If someone has any idea upon this matter would be greatly appreciated!

**Important edit that fits more in my problem**:

In my case the complex equation that i have, came through the dsolve() for a 2nd order differential equation. For the exp() element that exist in nympy this is a valid solution, it's not the same as an arbitary equation. However my equation is just a the above one regarding it's complexity

I include my code:

```
import scipy as sp
from sympy import*
import sympy as syp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

t, z, w, C2=symbols('t, z, w, C2')
x=Function('x')
eq=x(t).diff(t,2)+2*z*w*x(t).diff(t,1)+w**2*x(t)
sol=dsolve(eq,x(t),ics={x(0):0,x(t).diff(t,1).subs(t,0):2*C2*w*sqrt(z**2-1)})
```

next I want to substitute the z,w parameters in order to fit my data and then with a loop to make an array that takes the numerical solutions in order to plot them. I've tried the following:

```
for i in range(1000):
    step.append(i)
numdata=[]
for i in range(1000):
    numdata.append(N(sol.rhs.subs(t,i).subs(w,10).subs(z,0.001)))
```

However this can't work as the `sol` is an complex function. After this long journey I try to find (meaning of my life) ways to seperate the real and imaginary parts of this kind of function.
Thank you for being with me so far, you are a hero reagrdless of the result.

Comment: `sympy` and `numpy` are not integrated.  Don't use them together unless you really need to.  And even expect some gliches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sympy` has `re` and `im` functions:

```
In [113]: exp(complex(2,1))                                                                          
Out[113]: 
                  1.0⋅ⅈ
7.38905609893065⋅ℯ     

In [114]: re(exp(complex(2,1)))                                                                      
Out[114]: 3.99232404844127

In [115]: im(exp(complex(2,1)))                                                                      
Out[115]: 6.21767631236797

In [116]: exp(complex(2,1)).evalf()                                                                  
Out[116]: 3.99232404844127 + 6.21767631236797⋅ⅈ
```

`.real` and `.imag` are attributes (possibly implemented as properties) of `numpy` arrays (and complex python numbers).

Exploring `sympy` a bit more:

```
In [152]: expand(exp(y),complex=True)                                                                
Out[152]: 
   re(y)               re(y)           
ⅈ⋅ℯ     ⋅sin(im(y)) + ℯ     ⋅cos(im(y))

In [153]: expand(exp(complex(2,1)),complex=True)                                                     
Out[153]: 3.99232404844127 + 6.21767631236797⋅ⅈ
```

---

Your `sol`:

```
In [157]: sol                                                                                        
Out[157]: 
                 ⎛        ________⎞           ⎛        ________⎞
                 ⎜       ╱  2     ⎟           ⎜       ╱  2     ⎟
             t⋅w⋅⎝-z - ╲╱  z  - 1 ⎠       t⋅w⋅⎝-z + ╲╱  z  - 1 ⎠
x(t) = - C₂⋅ℯ                       + C₂⋅ℯ                      

In [181]: f1 = sol.rhs.subs({w:10, z:0.001,C2:1})                                                    

In [182]: f1                                                                                         
Out[182]: 
   10⋅t⋅(-0.001 - 0.999999499999875⋅ⅈ)    10⋅t⋅(-0.001 + 0.999999499999875⋅ⅈ)
- ℯ                                    + ℯ
```

Making a `numpy` compatible function:

```
In [187]: f = lambdify(t, f1)                                                                        

In [188]: print(f.__doc__)                                                                           
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(t)

Expression:

-exp(10*t*(-0.001 - 0.999999499999875*I)) + exp(10*t*(-0.001 +...

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(t):
    return (-exp(10*t*(-0.001 - 0.999999499999875*1j)) + exp(10*t*(-0.001 + 0.999999499999875*1j)))


Imported modules:
```

evaluate it at a range of values:

```
In [189]: f(np.arange(10))                                                                           
Out[189]: 
array([0.+0.j        , 0.-1.07720771j, 0.+1.78972745j, 0.-1.91766624j,
       0.+1.43181934j, 0.-0.49920326j, 0.-0.57406585j, 0.+1.44310044j,
       0.-1.83494157j, 0.+1.63413971j])
```

same values with just `sympy`:

```
In [199]: [im(f1.evalf(subs={t:i})) for i in range(10)]                                              
Out[199]: 
[0, -1.0772077135423, 1.78972744700845, -1.9176662437755, 1.43181934232583, -0.499203257243971, -0.
574065847629935, 1.44310044143674, -1.83494157235822, 1.63413971490123]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this issues arises because you are trying to do a `from numpy import *` along with `from sympy import *`

> Since both numpy and and sympy have their own definition of exp. The error is telling you that the Mul object does not have a exp method, since the interpreter is now confused between the sympy and numpy methods.

Therefore I would recommend doing this instead -

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
```

[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640759/what-causes-this-error-attributeerror-mul-object-has-no-attribute-cos-in)

After that you can simply do -

```
np.exp(complex(2,1)).imag
#Output - 6.217676312367968

np.exp(complex(2,1)).real
#Output - 3.992324048441272

np.exp(complex(2,1))
#Output - (3.992324048441272+6.217676312367968j)
```

---

**EDIT:** Since you get the output from a sympy dsolve() you can try using the alternate form of

> **e^(a+ib) = e^a*cos(b) + ie^a*sin(b)**

```
c = complex(2,1)

complex(sp.exp(c.real)*sp.cos(c.imag), sp.exp(c.real)*sp.sin(c.imag))
#Output - (3.992324048441272+6.217676312367968j)

sp.exp(c.real)*sp.cos(c.imag)
#Output - 3.992324048441272

sp.exp(c.real)*sp.sin(c.imag)
#Output - 6.217676312367968
```

---

**EDIT 2 :** You could `lambdify` your function and then solve to get real and imag parts.

```
expp = lambdify([(t,z,w,C2)],sol.rhs)
expp((1,complex(4,3),4,6))
#output - (4.234414847842685+1.053014400461299j)

expp((1,complex(4,3),4,6)).real
#output - 4.234414847842685

expp((1,complex(4,3),4,6)).imag
#output - 1.053014400461299
```

Comment: Thank you very much and for this exact question you are very correct! In my case it doesn't work as the complex equation that i have, came through the dsolve() for a 2nd order differential equation. For the exp() element that exist in nympy this is a valid solution, it's not the same as an arbitary equation. However my equation is just a the above one regarding it's complexity. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've edited my question as best as possible. I hope that make clearer the field rather than a pit of ... Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: the alternate form I mentioned above doesn't work for you? ```e^(a+ib) = e^acos(b) + ie^asin(b)```

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't make the equation by myself. I am a newbe on this and i don't know how to rephrase in terms of python "words".
The best fit for your answer could be to try something like: `np.sol.real` but this is nonsense.
Something else that i tried is `np.real(sol)` but the result is also nonesense, as it just takes the whole complex function as it is and prints it as a solution.

Comment: do check my updated answer. I use ```lamdify``` on ```sol.rhs```